# datepicker changedate not defined

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

i'm trying to use the bootstrap datepicker and i need the event changeDate. So i took the doc

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on(picker_event, function(e){
        # `e` here contains the extra attributes
    });
```

and i adapt it with the changeDate event

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on(changeDate, function(e){
        alert('yolotest');
    });
```

The sad thing is that he sees changeDate as an unknown variable (which causes the error changeDate is not defined) instead of an event.

i'm really stuck right now and i wanted to know if you have an idea on how to make this work. I don't see why he thinks `changeDate` is a variable instead of an event (i tried `changedate` , `Changedate` and `ChangeDate` , same error )

Answer (score 4):

You need to have `' '` around changeDate:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e){
        alert('yolotest');
    });
```